# AWS S3 display file inline instead of force download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For some reason files in my S3 bucket are being forced as downloads instead of displaying in-line so if I copy an image link and paste it into address bar and then navigate to it, it will promote my browser to download it. Instead I actually have to click on open image to go to the url.

Any ways to change the way files are served from S3

Comment: When you copy image link, it directly points to the image URL. Browser simply understands to execute the URL provided.

Comment: @SunilGulabani But I seen sites using amazon s3 that allow you to access the file directly without having to force download the file. For example image hosting sites allow for direct image access. I am referring to direct file-path here is an example this is a file hosted in my S3 bucket: https://droplet-files.s3.amazonaws.com/7c32280bbcb1d3e67ac799ce9c71212f.JPG

Comment: I think your content type provided will be wrong while uploading the image. It needs to be image/jpeg. Check for Content-Type: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: @SunilGulabani I don't send any data to S3 on regards on MINE type. I just simply: $s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) and whola

Comment: Use
$s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, array(
            'contentType' => 'image/jpeg',
            'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
));

Comment: You can get rid of this by making your image public. Click on the bucket in your console then click on image which you have uploaded and click action on the top then make public option in that drop down

Answer (score 100):

You need to define the content type, see below:

```
$client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => 'buckname',
        'Key'        => $destination,
        'SourceFile' => $source,
        'ContentType' =>'image/jpeg', //<-- this is what you need!
        'ACL'          => 'public-read'//<-- this makes it public so people can see it
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for 'ContentType' =>'image/jpeg', //<-- this is what you need!

Comment: 'ContentType' =>'image/jpeg',  sill downloads the url instead of diplay in browser

Comment: @insivika try open in an incognito browser. I had the same problema, it worked for me when i opened in anonymous mode.

Comment: Indeed works in a new browser or incognito.

Comment: I really hate that S3 decides how the data gets presented. I have an app that on some pages there is a download link (so I want the file to download). On other pages I want to view the file in a modal. This can't be done with the way S3 works unless you upload 2 files. 1 with the ContentType and one without. Why can't the developer decide what happens with the file?

Comment: why does it work with incognito window and doesn't work with normal one? have set my file's content type to `text/plain`, but it doesn't open in a normal window.

Comment: Converting the file format works too.

Answer (score 55):

You need to change the Content-Type. From the S3 console, right click on the object and select Properties then it's under Metadata. You can also do it programmatically: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/change_content_type

Comment: I see, I was using $s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) before, but for some reason I recall doing the same that I want to achieved with use of bucket policy

Comment: @Cl' you can also [set content-type in `putObject()` method](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#putObject) (as `putObjectFile()` is legacy now).

Answer (score 19):

You need to specify Content Disposition as well for inline instead attachment .

```
$client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => 'buckname',
    'Key'        => $destination,
    'SourceFile' => $source,
    'ContentType' =>'image/jpeg', //<-- this is what you need!
    'ContentDisposition' => 'inline; filename=filename.jpg', //<-- and this !
    'ACL'          => 'public-read'//<-- this makes it public so people can see it
));
```

Comment: This worked for me. For those looking to get this code working with any type of file be sure to use 'ContentType' => mime_content_type($file)

Answer (score 18):

if you are using python, you can set [ContentType as follows](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

mimetype = 'image/jpeg' # you can programmatically get mimetype using the `mimetypes` module
s3.upload_file(
    Filename=local_path,
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=remote_path,
    ExtraArgs={
        "ContentType": mimetype
    }
)
```

You can also achieve the same in aws cli. Note `*.jpeg` Check [s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html) documentation

```
aws s3 cp \
      --exclude "*" \
      --include "*.jpeg" \
      --content-type="image/jpeg"  \
      --metadata-directive="REPLACE" \
      --recursive \
      --dryrun \
       s3://<bucket>/<path>/ \
       s3://<bucket>/<path>/
```

Alternatively if you'd want to do modify one object at a time you might want to use [s3api copy-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html)

```
aws s3api copy-object \
    --content-type="image/jpeg" \
    --metadata-directive="REPLACE" \
    --copy-source "<bucket>/<key>" \
    --bucket "<bucket>" \
    --key "<key>" \
    --acl public-read
```

Answer (score 6):

You can change the content type from the AWS S3 Console too.

[image]

Then you will get to see the side pop up, use that to change it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try this one, this works for me.

```
const params = {
          Bucket: 'bucket-name',
          Body: file,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          ContentType: contentType,
          ContentEncoding: 'base64',
          ContentDisposition: 'attachment',
        };
```

Comment: You can get contentType from tmp in php.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one, ContentType is compulsory for open in a browser if you have already opened any URL on the browser then try in incognito.

```
var params = {
            Bucket: config.BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: fileName,
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentDisposition: 'inline',
            ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
            Body: buf
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out that if we pass an empty value to `ContentType` it will open the file instead of downloading.

This is actually nice when uploading files of all kind of extensions.

```
$s3->putObject(
[
    'Bucket' => ..,
    'Key' => ..,
    'Body' => ..,
    'ContentType' => '', <---
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
]);
```

Comment: I was facing same in python , added "     bucket.put_object(Key=key,Body=strdata,ACL='public-read',ContentType='text/html'), and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. The problem was the `Content-type` property, when I was saving the file in s3. I am using Spring Boot, and content data in s3 was saving  `application/octet-stream` in the value properties instead of `image/jpeg`, for example. Therefore, when I opened the file link, the browser downloaded the file.

The solution for this problem is to change the `Content-type` before saving the file in s3 !

Answer (score 1):

In case someone who is using Java SDK is finding a solution for this, you need to set content type to ObjectMetaData.

```
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setContentType("image/png");

s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest
    (bucketName, fileName + ".png", inputStream, 
     objectMetadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these two properties to force browsers to inline the file from s3:

'ResponseContentType' & 'ResponseContentDisposition'

You can use them in the getCommand when generating a signed URL

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
        'Key' => $filename,
        'ResponseContentType' =>  get_mime_type($filename),
        'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'inline; filename='.$user_filename
    ]);
```

get_mime_type is just my custom function to return mime type using the file name

This is what I used when I faced the same problem, I have millions of files in my s3 bucket and I couldn't change the mime type individually in console

Answer (score 1):

What really worked for me was to set the `ContentType` params to `image/png`  before saving the S3 file.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is pretty old question but when i was googling a similar issue then I landed here so for them who lands here, just wanted to clarify that why files are being downloaded instead of displaying it - Because when you don't set the `Content-Type` explicitly, then by default S3 set the `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open it in incognito it will work other than that it will not work for some reason.

Comment: If that's the case try clearing your browser cache and restarting the browser.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of fighting, this is the code I want. 
Here is the code for anyone who uses "generate_presigned_post" in python

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                  aws_access_key_id="<aws_access_key_id>",
                  aws_secret_access_key="<aws_secret_access_key>",
                  config=Config(
                      region_name="<region_name>",
                      signature_version="<signature_version>"
                  ))

key = 'bbb.png'

creds = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket="<Bucket>",
    Key=key,
    Fields={"Content-Type": "image/png"},
    Conditions=[{"Content-Type": "image/png"}],
    ExpiresIn=3600)
```

Answer (score -1):

### Below code worked for me but pdf not open in browser only jpeg or png file open in the browser.

```
$result = $s3->putObject(
            array(
                'Bucket'                =>  $bucketName,
                'Key'                   =>  $keyName,
                'SourceFile'            =>  $file,
                'StorageClass'          =>  'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
                'ContentEncoding'       =>  'base64',
                'ContentDisposition'    =>  'inline',
                'ContentType'           =>  'image/jpeg', //<-- this is what you need!
                'ACL'                   =>  'public-read'//<-- this makes it public so people can see it
            )
        );
```