# Using PDF.js to view pdf files currently held in AWS-s3

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pdf.js

I am trying to display my pdf files using PDF.js.  If my pdf file is in the same folder/ server (my EC2 instance) as my webpage file, then pdf.js is able to display the pdf file.  However, when i use a downloadable link from my AWS-s3 (where my pdf files are stored), the pdf viewer does not display the content, instead it downloads it - which is not what i want.  Please can someone advise on the best strategy to get this to work?

```
 <div id="wrap">
        <a href="https://s3-eu-west-myPath/rab3.7M.pdf">Test PDF Viewer</a>

 </div>
```

Comment: What is the `Content-type` that your file has in S3 (the Metadata in the S3 console)?

Comment: I don't believe the console provides that info.  perhaps you could direct me?

Comment: In the AWS console, go to the bucket and then file.  Select the file.  Under the "Properties" tab, select "Metadata".  AWS will have picked a `Content-Type` for you for the file.  It is likely `application/pdf` but I wanted to make sure.  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150854/aws-s3-display-file-inline-instead-of-force-download).

Comment: the Content-Type  is  'application/octet-stream'

Comment: @stdunbar You are correct. I changed it to 'application/pdf' and now it displays the pd instead of downloading it. if you owuld like to out it down as an answer i can can accept it. thanks!