# Nginx to serve contents of S3 files in browser

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to open files from S3 served by Nginx in a browser. Was unable to get it working with following config

Files in S3 buckets are text files with extension `.manefiest`

```
location /manefiest/ {
    proxy_pass http://my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/;
    types {
        text/html manefiest;
        text/plain manefiest;
    }
}
```

I want browser to show the contents of the file. But with above config it was downloading the file.

Whats wrong here ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150854/aws-s3-display-file-inline-instead-of-force-download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `contentType:"text/plain"` for uploaded file solved the problem.

Thanks @ofirule