# Presigned URL's downloading files instead of opening in browser

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I have generated a `presigned URL` using `boto3` for my flask application. Essentially, the presigned URL is for accessing specific files on my `AWS s3` server.

However, whenever I go to the presigned URL, it downloads the file, when I would like it to just display the file in the browser, as you can with local files.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 display file inline instead of force download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150854/aws-s3-display-file-inline-instead-of-force-download)

Comment: `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` are there to help :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.