# Apple's apple-app-site-association file on S3 with CloudFront Distribution

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, apple-app-site-association

I am trying to serve apple-app-site-association from the S3 via CloudFront distribution via my custom domain.

But when I am given a path like below, It's started downloading rather than showing in the browser.

[https:/mycustomdonain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association](http://https:/mycustomdonain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association)

Do I need to make any setting at S3 or CloudFront level to make it work?

Note: The application is developed in Angular.

Thanks

Comment: The browser will determine if it will download a file or display it depending on the value of the Content-Type (sometimes in combination with Content-Disposition) header. If the value is application/json it will most probably be displayed. S3 automatically applies content type for files you are upload Amazon S3 usually based on their extension. I believe if you set the type of the file to `application/json` it will be displayed, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150854/aws-s3-display-file-inline-instead-of-force-download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Christos says, you need to set the content-type response header in S3, which then also applies to Cloudfront HTTPS URLs.

Here is an example of mine, that I use for deep linking and OpenID Connect with an HTTPS redirect URI:

- https://mobile.authsamples.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

Further details on how this looks in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/23/ios-code-sample-infrastructure/), where you set the content type by editing tte file properties:

[image: File Properties]