# Apple app site association issue on AWS CloudFront with S3

Tags: amazon-s3, web, amazon-cloudfront, applinks

I checked the following headers to ~/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

[image]

Content-Type is applicaion/json.
But There is the following error

- Your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.

My Setup

- S3 static web
- Cloudfront (Add content-type: applicaion/json to the header when responding to the .well-known/apple-app-site-association file.)

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70211954/apples-apple-app-site-association-file-on-s3-with-cloudfront-distribution?rq=2