# Why is OVH S3 temp url downloads instead of being displayed within the iframe?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, ovh

When generating an OVH S3 tempURL pointing to an HTML file and adding it to an iframe's src attribute, the file gets downloaded instead of displaying it.

```
<iframe style="width:100%;max-width:860px;display:block;margin:auto;padding:50px; border:none;" scrolling="no" src="https://storage.GRA.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_09b2a1dadcfb457dbcf5b28deebae0bc/XXXXX/cms/35/es/testdoc35/html?temp_url_sig=50532a640d1dceb3290a63a9a0cabd6c57462d0e&temp_url_expires=1657349539"></iframe>
```

I'm getting the URL like this:

```
 $url = Storage::disk('ovh')->temporaryUrl($path, now()->addMinutes(1),   [
            'CONTENT_DISPOSITION' => 'inline',
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'text/html'
        ]);
```

Although `CONTENT_DISPOSITION` and `CONTENT_TYPE` seems to be ignored.

Any clue on how can I display the file instead of downloading it?

I know I can do `return Storage::disk('ovh')->get($path);`, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. I would like the iframe to load the content directly from the S3.

*Using Laravel 9*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 display file inline instead of force download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150854/aws-s3-display-file-inline-instead-of-force-download)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @luk2302 - I set the content type to text/html but I still got the same issue, even if I try in a new incognito window

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#temporary-urls), you should be using `ResponseContentType` instead of `CONTENT_TYPE`

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward , but that's for AWS, it doesn't seem to work for OVH