# Display S3 Pre-Sign URL when in embed/iframe file and avoid downloading

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, pre-signed-url

I have an HTML file stored on s3 and I am trying to display it in embed/iframe tag but it's downloading the file instead of displaying it. I have added `type=text/html` in the embed tag but it's still downloading the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 display file inline instead of force download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150854/aws-s3-display-file-inline-instead-of-force-download)

Comment: It seems to be a similar problem with displaying Image files, I was primarily working with embedding HTML files inside another HTML page, not the image file. Though the commands are useful and can be used for changing content-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like when I uploaded the file the default Content-Type saved was binary/octat-stream:
[image]

Update it to `text/html`
[image]

Now the file is properly displayed in embed/iframe tag and not getting downloaded

Comment: You can also specify the content type while uploading the file or edit it after the file is uploaded.

Comment: Is there any other way, without changing the metadata in AWS S3? I only have public link and not access to the s3

Comment: Top of the head, not a good solution but still which can work given S3 access is not there, would be to create a middleware service or API which on page load fetches the file from s3, modify it and then send response as required.